# MySQL order by date (M D, Y, H:M:S am\pm)

Tags: mysql, date

I've been messing around with this for hours trying different ways of ordering by date. I wish there was an strtotime(field) that would do what I need.

I've tried messing around with UNIX_TIMESTAMP, STR_TO_DATE and I just can't figure this out.

I'm trying to put these in order given below:

```
June 13, 2012, 4:45:28 pm
May  31, 2012, 10:41   am
June 12, 2012, 6:40:34 pm
June 06, 2012, 3:05:22 am
June 10, 2012, 7:59:31 pm
```

I've tried a bunch of different approaches, this is the latest one I've been working on...

```
SELECT name,lastonline FROM `users` ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(UPPER(lastonline),
       '%M %d,%Y, %H:%i:%s') DESC
```

It seems as though this is as close as I can get and it doesn't take into account "AM" or "PM". I've tried adding the %p on the end, but for some reason it's as though the UPPER isn't doing anything at all. I've also tried using %r.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose fixing the schema so it's a date-related type instead of text is out of the question?

Comment: Yes, it has to be stored as a varchar unless someone is going to go through all of the code every time a date is referenced and fix it... I didn't code it to use a varchar date, I always just use strtotime when inputting into a database or timestamp.

Comment: In the long term, I think it would be better to do that work. Your schema is fundamentally broken - why do the conversions all over the place?

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(UPPER(lastonline),'%M %d,%Y, %H:%i:%s %p')` - this does by no means mean, that I zhink your scheme is sound.

Comment: I've already tried that, that's just adding a %p. That doesn't work.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(UPPER('June 13, 2012, 4:45:28 pm'),'%M %d, %Y, %r')` works (just tried it)

Comment: Add that as an answer, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) say, that a construct of 12-Hour time and AM/PM should be parsed as `%r` in one piece, not as `%H:%i:%s %p`.

While I consider this to be a misfeature, it definitly works.

Answer (score 0):

you may use `HH24` instead to get a full range of hours.